# WordPress: Elementor plugin is adding <br> in button

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

Hope everyone doing well!

I am making a site in WordPress through Elementor plugin. I am facing a weird issue on the button. Button has line break `<br>`, even I didn't add it there.

[image]

But on the other hand, the button is showing alright in Elementor dashboard, but when I do a live preview, button messed up.

[image]

I tried to deactivate all plugins and themes, but it didn't work. Need Help!

Comment: Can you view the generated source code and edit it? Perhaps in the advanced tab?

Comment: I didn't do any changes in the style or advanced tab.

Comment: I understand, are you asking for help to resolve the issue, or do you want an explanation of what happened? If it's the former, then I'm suggesting that you'll need to edit the HTML source code somehow...

Comment: Can you change the type of button to something else? Perhaps 'warning' contains those extra elements for "warnings" : )

Comment: yup, i already changed the type of button, but it doesn't work, i have to create a custom button through html and css :(

Comment: Is there no option to edit the HTML in the Elementor editor?

Comment: Yea, I guess just add the button using the HTML widget instead. I can't comment on whether it's a bug or not because I've not used Elementor before, perhaps contact their support?

Comment: you are right, i have to do it in HTML, anyway. thank you so much for your precious time. i appreciate it.

Comment: Plus i didn't understand, why i got a negative vote. like they didn't read my question carefully? or is this an offtopic?

Comment: That was me, because I couldn't get an answer to my first question when I was trying to help. If you edit your question, in any way, I'll be able to remove the negative vote as I understand what you were saying now. Glad you figured it out anyway : )

Comment: I'm not an authority on the subject, but I don't think there was anything particularly wrong with your question, and I shouldn't have marked you down so sorry about that. Edit the question and I'll vote you up (I can't change my vote unless you edit the question) : )

Comment: No problem Matt! I have edited the question. And I appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: There you go! It works both ways, now I know what Elementor is and a little about it's limitations etc... I'm not a fan of such plugins myself, I use ACF. Check it out if you want to and have some time, I manage nearly all my content in Wordpress with ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com - take it easy : )

Comment: Thanks @GamersAgenda : )

Comment: Here's more info on how WordPress adds markup to content: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign a custom class tag to the button element, it most likely would be assigned to the div .elementor-button-wrapper, you’ll have to check it with dev tools, then you need to access the theme style on appearance/editor. So you could add the following code:

```
.class-used br{
    display:none;
}
```

In case the class you assigned to the button is not in a parent tag on top of all 
 you need to eliminate try the same process assigning the class to the column or element that wraps the button. Hope it give you an idea to solve the issue.

Comment: A clunky workaround, but it saved my bacon before a critical presentation! At least, it buys me more some more time until I figure out what's actually causing this pesky issue... To dig more into the root cause(s), as mentioned by @admcfajn in the comments above, one should probably check out the responses on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/stop-wordpress-automatically-adding-br-tags-to-post-content

Answer (score 1):

button or link padding, width, margin and other style won't work. Because button or link need to add **display:inline-block; or display: block;** then it will be work. So you need to use that **display:inline-block; or display: block;**. Hope it helps